# How to show data from an old component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a component that receives data from the file. Now, while loading this data from the server, it shows Loader. I want that when updating the component, it shows not the Loader, but the old component. If remove the loader, then the data does not have time to load and element shows zeros. How to do it?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {mapToArr} from '../helpers';
import Table from './Table';
import Loader from './Loader';
import {loadAllTables} from '../AC'

class TablesList extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        tables: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        const {loaded, loading, loadAllTables} = this.props;
        if (!loaded || !loading) loadAllTables();
    };

    render() {
        const { tables, loading } = this.props;
        if (loading) return <Loader/>;

        const tablesElements = tables.map(table =>
            <Table table = {table} key = {table.id}/>
        );

        return (
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    {tablesElements}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    };

};

export default connect((state) => {
    return {
        tables: mapToArr(state.tables.entities),
        loading: state.tables.loading,
        loaded: state.tables.loaded
    }
}, {loadAllTables})(TablesList);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the architecture of your application.

Lets assume, that `state.tables.entities` store our data. Then we change `state.tables.loading` to `state.tables.status`.

Our `status` field must be declared as string variable, that can be `'FETCH'`, `'COMPLETE'` or `'DIRTY'`.

When status is `'DIRTY'` we show `Loading` component. When status is `'FETCH'` we show old data in component.

There is some example of it:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {mapToArr} from '../helpers';
import Table from './Table';
import Loader from './Loader';
import {loadAllTables} from '../AC'

class TablesList extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        tables: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
        status: PropTypes.oneOf(['FETCH', 'COMPLETE', 'DIRTY']
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        const {status} = this.props;
        if (status === 'DIRTY') loadAllTables();
    };

    render() {
        const { tables, status } = this.props;
        if (status === 'DIRTY') return <Loader/>;

        const tablesElements = tables.map(table =>
            <Table table = {table} key = {table.id}/>
        );

        return (
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    {tablesElements}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    };

};

export default connect((state) => {
    return {
        tables: mapToArr(state.tables.entities),
        status: state.tables.status,
    }
}, {loadAllTables})(TablesList);
```

Now your `loadAllTables` action creator call several actions:
-`FETCH_TABLE_DATA`, that doesn't change `state.tables.entities`, but change `state.tables.status` to `FETCH`
- `RECEIVE_TABLE_DATA`, which changes `state.tables.entities` and set `state.tables.status` to `COMPLETE`.